# PHP File Upload to FTP (Here Using Uploadify as FTP) -- Unable to perform upload

Tags: php, html, xampp, connection, uploadify

```
Here is my HTML Code :

<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome</title>
</head>

<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile_1" type="file" /><br />
Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile_2" type="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload Files" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And Below is PHP :

```
<?php
$ftp_server = "94.xx.1.xxx";
$ftp_username   = "anxxxxxx";
$ftp_password   =  "xxxxxxxxx";

$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("could not connect to $ftp_server");

if(@ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_username, $ftp_password))
{
  echo "connected as $ftp_username@$ftp_server\n";
  }
else {
  echo "could not connect as $ftp_username\n";
}

$file = $_FILES["uploadedfile_1"]["name"];
$file2 = $_FILES["uploadedfile_2"]["name"];

$remote_file_path = "ansxxxx@94.xx.1.xxx/JustForTest".$file; // This is the Folder which I've created inside the FTP 
$remote_file_path2 = "ansxxxx@94.xx.1.xxx/JustForTest".$file2; // This is the Folder which I've created inside the FTP 

ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file_path, $_FILES["uploadedfile_1"]["tmp_name"],FTP_ASCII);
ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file_path2, $_FILES["uploadedfile_2"]["tmp_name"],FTP_ASCII);
ftp_close($conn_id);
echo "\n\nconnection closed";
?>
```

Error :

> connected as anshxxx@94.xx.1.xxx
> Fatal error: Uncaught ValueError: Path cannot be empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\upload.php:22 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\upload.php(22): ftp_put(Object(FTP\Connection), 'anshxxx@94.xx...', '', 1) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\upload.php on line 22

It connects perfectly...but no files gets uploaded, throws the above error. I am new to php. PLEASE HELP...!

I would prefer to share the code, if anyone had done such kind of requirement.

Thanks a ton in Advance...!`

Comment: Do some debugging, like checking what `$_FILES["uploadedfile_1"]["tmp_name"]` and `$_FILES["uploadedfile_2"]["tmp_name"]` actually contains. Do a `var_dump($_FILES)` and check. If they are empty, check if the `error` is anything other than `0` (which would indicate an upload error, like file too large or something). Never just assume both files are successfully uploaded, always validate and verify the data you get.

Comment: And why are you using `FTP_ASCII` when uploading files instead of the default `FTP_BINARY`? Will it always be text files?

Comment: Tried Didn't work.

Comment: You have a problem with your remote file path I believe. You should not use pseudo directory names in your path like username@server.ip etc. You must be sure if this kind of directory names are allowed on the FTP server. Another question is, are you sure that you upload 2 files when you test? If you upload just one file, it is normal to get this error. Because the upload path would be empty to the second file.

Comment: I posted a solution, please try it and post any error messages if it is the case.

Comment: _"Tried Didn't work"_ - Tried what exactly? And how didn't it work? You need to be _way_ more specific. I also told you to add debugging to get more information to share.

Comment: Hi @SelimAcar The Below Code :

I have changed -- Line 25 as $remoteDirectory = "/JustForTest";

Result = connected as anshu9453@94.23.1.139 connection closed

Images are not there in the "/JustForTest" Directory.

Also, Thanks a ton for the code. I have defined my remote directory as "/JustForTest"

Comment: Hi @SelimAcar Any Help?

Comment: @DivyanshSharma Please check my comment under my solution

Answer (score 0):

Try following code. Please redefine your upload directory in the code. I wrote a comment to your question, that you should use safe directory names. I would not use @ and . in directory names. Especially no dots.

```php
<?php

// Build FTP connection and login
function getFtpConnection()
{
    $ftp_server = "94.xx.1.xxx";
    $ftp_username   = "anxxxxxx";
    $ftp_password   =  "xxxxxxxxx";
    
    $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("could not connect to $ftp_server");
    
    if(@ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_username, $ftp_password))
    {
      echo "connected as $ftp_username@$ftp_server\n";
      return $conn_id;
    }
    else {
      echo "could not connect as $ftp_username\n";
      return false;
    }
}

$messages = [];
if(gettype($conn) == "resource")
{
    $remoteDirectory = "/html/myuploadDir/";//Absoulte path
    foreach($_FILES as $k => $upload_file)
    {
        if(!empty($upload_file["name"]) && filesize($upload_file["tmp_name"]) > 0)
        {
            $fname = $upload_file["name"];
            $remote_filepath = $remoteDirectory . $fname;
            if(ftp_put($conn, $remote_filepath, $upload_file["tmp_name"]))
                $messages[] = "File $fname uploaded successfully";
            else
                $messages[] = "Upload for file $fname failed";
        }
    }
    ftp_close($conn);
    $messages[] = "Connection closed";
}
echo implode("<br>", $messages);
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks a ton for the above code. I have defined my remote directory as "/JustForTest

Comment: Also I am uploading 2 files at a time @Selim Acar

Comment: @DivyanshSharma $remoteDirectory = "/JustForTest" may be wrong. Because the directory JustForTest has to be in the ROOT directory of your FTP-server in that case. Please try without remoteDirectory: `$remote_filepath = $upload_file["name"]`. If the upload succeeds, then search for the file on the FTP server where the file was saved. According to the path you can define your target directory either as absolute or relative path.

Comment: I have changed the below code.

//$remote_filepath = "$remoteDirectory/" . $upload_file["name"];
   $remote_filepath = $upload_file["name"];
            ftp_put($conn, $remote_filepath, $upload_file["tmp_name"]);
        }
    }
    ftp_close($conn);
    echo "\n\nconnection closed";    
}

?>

Result: connected as axxxxxx@91.xx.x.xxx connection closed.
*No Upload Happens.

Comment: @DivyanshSharma I updated my solution above. It does not contain huge changes. Please define your remote directory path. Pay attention the remote upload directory path should be absolute path and that directory should have proper access rights or persmissions. Write access should be allowed on that folder. I tested this code with my own FTP account (remote dir /html) and it worked. Please be sure that your Firewall does not block your connection either.

Comment: @DivyanshSharma Could you get it work?

Comment: I've managed the below code, and it's working but now I need Auto-Number File Rename in the Uploaded Files, in Remote Server. Below is the code.